# Setting value for a textbox - jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to set the value of a textbox to null via jquery.  I tried

```
 onclick="$('#c_album').val('TEST VALUE');" at the submit button

$('input#c_album').val('hello'); - in the script section
```

Appreciate assitance

Thanks
Dave

[edit]-- this is the code i am using

```
$('#submit').bind('click',(function(){
        $('#src_box').val('hello');
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    $(function(){
       $('#btnSubmit').bind('click', function(){
           $('input#c_album').val('hello');
// OR
           $('#c_album').val('hello');
// OR
           $('input[id=c_album]').val('hello');
       });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

If the id of the textbox is #c_alcum then you can use

```
$("#c_album").val('hello');
```

Although you can use a tag selector in front of the id selector, there is no need to use that since id will be unique in a document.

If you want to set the value after the ajax function completion then you can insert this code in the callback function for the ajax request.

***Edit***

Are you putting all these codes inside the document ready event

```
$(function(){
   // All code goes here
});
```

Also remove the onlick handler and do it in jquery way like

```
$("#yourbuttonid").click ( function(){
});
```

or

```
$("#yourbuttonid").bind ( "click" , function() {
});
```

You can't put a null value inside a textbox. You can insert an empty string value inside it like

```
$("#c_album").val('');
```

Comment: @pulse: its a search box, now when the user clicks the search button, he is presented with his search and the search text box value should be null

Comment: @pulse: tried all of the above nope it does not work
generally I use $("#c_album").val('');

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('#mybutton').click(function(e){
        $('input#c_album').val('hello');
    });
});
```

Is a general method which should work. Without knowing more of your code it's hard to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

it worked, the error was, there was no id for the textbox

```
<input type='text' name='text' id='text'>
```

Thanks all of you..

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#submit').bind('click',(function(){
        $('#src_box').val('hello');
    });
```

There is a problem in this code, so try this -

```
$('#submit').bind('click',function(){
        $('#src_box').val('hello');
    });
```

The problem is you have used a '(' before the function().
But now it will work fine **:)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "fetchBeaconName",
   data: "beaconMajorId=" + val,
   async: true,
   success: function (data) {
       $.each(data.beaconList, function () {
            $("#beaconName").val(this.beaconName);
       });
   },
   error: function (data) {
       alert("No values found..!!");
   }
});
```

Comment: Explain what you did please